# Burninate: removing-whitespace

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

So apparently there are 351 questions tagged with [removing-whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace).

Seems like a open-and-shut case of a tag that needs to be ditched. Or rather, burninated.

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: So, other than concrete concepts we are also tagging "tasks"...

Comment: I'm not so sure why this tag would have to go. Could you amend your post by explaining your reasoning? The only argument I can see is that the [tag:whitespace] tag already covers the concept but I'm not even sure whether that is true, as [tag:whitespace] is only about white-space *characters* while [tag:removing-whitespace] also applies to “issues related to removing unwanted whitespace in (web-)design”.

Comment: @5gon12eder a common test against meta-tags and useless ones is the question "*Can anybody be an expert in it?*". Nobody in their right mind would follow something like [removing-whitespace].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering:

1. The 5 most [linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/removing-whitespace?filter=all&sort=linked) aren't even in the same language (python, objetive-c, c#, sql and vim)
2. No user consistently posts questions on this tag (bunch of one answer on the [top users page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/removing-whitespace/topusers))
3. Removing whitespaces as far as it goes depends heavily on the context of the problem, and unlike others similar cases, it isn't even a programing concept.
4. The tag appears most with [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace), not even a language tag.

We can burn. Nobody's going to miss it.

Comment: Just watch out for those few question that are actually in [whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace) ;) Better yet, untag the rest, and make [whitespace] a language tag.

Comment: @AndrasDeak UGGGGGGGGGH....

Comment: And *then* we can start a burnination request for the [whitespace] language tag, and tag *that* with [removing-whitespace].

Comment: @AndrasDeak you are making me scared...